# Application Spyder launch error in Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to launch spyder 5.2.2 on anaconda but I get this error saying "Application spyder launch may have produced errors." I am a beginner in coding and tried a few fixes from other answers. I previosly ran

```
conda update --all
```

and tried to fix it with this

```
conda remove spyder-kernels
conda install spyder-kernels=0.*
```

but it didn't help. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda multiple times but it did not help. How can I fix this? Below is the content of the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\abern\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\abern\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 237, in main
mainwindow.main(options, args)
File "C:\Users\abern\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 2016, in main
mainwindow = create_window(MainWindow, app, splash, options, args)
File "C:\Users\abern\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\utils.py", line 289, in create_window
main.setup()
File "C:\Users\abern\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 848, in setup
internal_plugins = find_internal_plugins()
File "C:\Users\abern\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\find_plugins.py", line 92, in find_internal_plugins
mod = importlib.import_module(entry_point.module_name)
File "C:\Users\abern\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 850, in exec_module
File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\abern\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\application\plugin.py", line 30, in 
from spyder.plugins.application.container import (
File "C:\Users\abern\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\application\container.py", line 31, in 
from spyder.plugins.console.api import ConsoleActions
File "C:\Users\abern\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\console\api.py", line 12, in 
from spyder.plugins.console.widgets.main_widget import (
File "C:\Users\abern\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\console\widgets\main_widget.py", line 35, in 
from spyder.plugins.console.widgets.internalshell import InternalShell
File "C:\Users\abern\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\console\widgets\internalshell.py", line 38, in 
from spyder.plugins.variableexplorer.widgets.objecteditor import oedit
File "C:\Users\abern\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\variableexplorer\widgets\objecteditor.py", line 16, in 
from spyder_kernels.utils.lazymodules import (
File "C:\Users\abern\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\utils\lazymodules.py", line 15, in 
from spyder_kernels.utils.misc import is_module_installed
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_module_installed' from 'spyder_kernels.utils.misc' (C:\Users\abern\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\utils\misc.py)
```

Comment: I think the correct version of `spyder-kernels` that works with Spyder 5.2.2 is [`spyder-kernels >=2.2.1; <2.3.0`](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/487ddd2170735e2ff51589d1ab2acef685356220/setup.py#L241)